# How do I run mysql_upgrade for wamp server or to get Mysql run

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp, wampserver

Today I installed a new version of wamp server on my computer (over the old one). The icon on the bottom right stays orange after starting wampserver. I found out that Mysql is not starting op. The Mysql log file shows errors like these:

```
[ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_instruments' has the wrong structure
[ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'setup_timers' has the wrong structure
[ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'performance_timers' has the wrong structure
```

After searching on the internet I found out that I probably have to run mysql_upgrade

I open the mysql.exe file (with administrator) in this folder C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin
but when I run the upgrade using this syntax: shell> mysql_upgrade; it returns a message that I have an error in my sql-syntax. (I tried it with all services on and with all services off) Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this? Or maybe there are other ways to get Mysql run.

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards, Liesbeth

Comment: Actually there sound like there is more to this. If the install completed properly mysql should be looking at the new `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data` folder for its database and the performance_scheme should be correct. Did you copy **ALL** the old databases to the new mysql version folder?

Answer (score 1):

The mysql_upgrade is a stand alone executable, not a DML or DDL command so it cannot be issued via mysql.exe program.

So first **MAKE A BACKUP OF ALL YOUR NEW DATABASE FOLDER** as this process can get destructive if things go wrong.

So backup \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data and all its subfolders, put this somewhere safe!

The copy your old databases to your new version folder.

```
copy \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql{old version}\data to \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data
```

Then you have to run mysql_upgrade.exe as an **administrator** so start a command window by right clicking the command window icon and selecting `Run as Administrator`

Then

```
cd into \wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin
```

Now you can issue the upgrade command like this:

```
mysql_upgrade.exe
```

Depending on how many databases you have it may take a little time, so dont panic, you have a backup anyway.